# sharing opened text file in different functions in C

Tags: c++, c

Pointers are not my strong ability in C lang. so I might need a little help from you guys :).
I want to work with my text file in different functions but i can open it in only my A() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void B(){
    // I want to work with FILE.TXT in this function without openining it here.

}

void A() {
    FILE *fr;
    fr = fopen("FILE.TXT","r");

    fclose(fr);
}

int main() {
char c;
while(c!='*') {
        c = getchar();
        if(c=='A') A(); 
        if(c=='B') B();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

thank you guys

Comment: Why has this been tagged as C++?

Comment: Do yourself (and us) a favor, study Tom Jensen's ["A tutorial on pointers and arrays in C"](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm). Yes, the document is quite old (and it shows in some archaic programming techniques and surprisingly small data types), but very much on topic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am so going to read it right now :) Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

Just pass the `FILE*` around as an argument to whichever function needs to do I/O.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("FILE.TXT", "r");
    // don't forget error checking

    A(fp);

    fclose(fp);
}

void A(FILE *fp)
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I cannot open the text FILE in main function. Is there a way to do it? must be something with pointers. Still thank you for your reply.

Comment: Why can't you open the file in main? This seems like the answer I'd use.

Comment: @Toesmash: then return it from `A`; but that will complicate the logic of the program needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You simply pass it on as a FILE pointer parameter to function B, like so:

> void B(FILE* const f){ 
>        //do stuff with f
>   
>  }

Answer (score 1):

To USE a file in a function, you will need to have the `FILE*` object in that function. There are a few different choices, these are the most obvious ones:

1. Open `fr` in main, and pass it to `A()` and `B()`
2. Make `fr` a global variable, open it in `A()` (make sure you don't close it!), use it in B().

I would prefer option 1. Using global variables makes code less readable in general.

Note also that your code allows B() to be called before A, which would attempt to use the file before it has been opened. Assuming you don't implement option 1, your code will need to ensure that this doesn't happen (or that it is somehow handled).

There is absolutely no way the file can be opened AND CLOSED in A, and then used in B.